# Do I need / can I run laravel backups froma controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backup

Here's a bit of context:

- Running Laravel 10, and SPATIE Backup v8;
- An admin should be able to choose, and this choice will be stored in a DB, to shedule backups (whatever the options (DB only , Files only , or both ..) or the timeframes ( 'e.g. ->every weeks, daily, etc...), those not  strictly relevant to my question :
- According to the admin's choice, a backup could be run immediately (upon click of a button, lauching a route, I guess...) or using a scheduled command , with the relevant options (I have not yet decided I I should suggest weekly or monthly backups, but these options should still be "allowed" / availables as scheduled tasks, obviously...
- Apparently using the backup commands , which are normally CLI commands  within controllers is complicated at best, or plain impossible ?

Anyway could someone kindly lead the way to a solution, for this, as I guess it's not such an unusual use case ...?

Many thanks,

JMB

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this; However there is no code to show. This was a question asked in broad but clear terms and someone understood this enough to answer usefully,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when the admin changes the Backup-related setting, you also want to change the scheduling cron. It is possible to do this from the controller. You can set a scheduling in Controller:

```
Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        switch ($adminChoice) {
        case 'daily':
            $schedule->command('backup:run')->daily();
            break;
        case 'weekly':
            $schedule->command('backup:run')->weekly();
            break;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks, I will try this out.

I do have doubts though if I can use SPATIE's backup in production on a shared server solution as it requires knowing the location of  mysqldump,which the provider says he cannot ...'provide'...
A way around this ?
Many thanks for your patience, and..
... I do understand this is a separate if related question so please, the OP, no terse remarks or useless comment on this: the people offering advice help  everyone in a similar situation... Thanks to @jeyhun

Comment: The SPATIE backup package allows you to set a custom mysqldump path in the config/backup.php configuration file. If you can find the path to mysqldump on your shared server, you can set it like this: ```'database_dump' => [
    'mysql' => [
        'dump_binary_path' => '/path/to/the/binary', 
        // ...
    ],
],
```

Comment: HI and thanks for your help

I know that the config requires the location of the mysqldump binary..That's just the issue: As I am  using a shared hosting provider, the location of the binaries are not available ... Is theer a way of discorering  it ? Or a way around this in the SPATIE plugin ? 

By the way your suggestion works perfectly, except (maybe to my low knowledge of LARAVEL,that I changed  the call & function to allow $adminChoice to be passed on from the function calling the schedule (Schedule $Schedule) function to schedule (Schedule $Shedule , $adminChoice) {...} ...

Comment: On a shared hosting environment, there are indeed restrictions that could prevent you from using certain features of the command line or scheduler as you would on a VPS or dedicated server. If the issue is related to not knowing the location of PHP binaries, you can create a PHP script to find the path to the PHP CLI: `<?php
echo 'PHP binary location: ' . PHP_BINARY;
?>` On shared hosting, you typically don't have the ability to add your own cron jobs via the command line. However, most shared hosting providers offer a way to add cron jobs through their control panel (like cPanel).

Comment: HI Again and many thanks for your answers...
I know that I have access to cron jobs via CPANEL, the 'traditioonnal way' , e.g. defining the job & schedule via crontab or some kind of more user-friendly form.

I understood that LARAVEL's scheduling was a substitute for this ?

I will try and locate the mysqldump binary using the PHP command you mentionned; THX

Comment: Hi So, if I understand rightly, if I am unable to locate the mysqldump on  my shared hosting, the only solution is to schedule my " scheduled jobs" 'manually', using the cpanel from my provider ? eg stating the route to run and setting the schedule in CPanel...?
A real shame...